# Python update user input with tkinter button

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm just starting with python and i'm having a problem. I've tried various solutions, but i can't update the field that says '19'. When i click on plus, i want it to be 20, then 21,... and when i click - it has to go back to 20 , 19. Can anybody tell me how to solve this?

```
 from tkinter import *

    def fct_tempplus():
        while True:
            #  tekstvak_input_user = tekstvak_input_user +1
            return tekstvak_input_user + 1

    def fct_tempmin():
        print ('ok')


    window = Tk()
    window.geometry("800x400")  # not *
    window.title("TEST")

    label= Label( window, text = "Temp?")
    label.place(x=350,y=175)


    tempplus=Button(window, bd=10,width=10, height = 1,text="+",command=fct_tempplus,
font=("Helvetica", 12))
    tempplus.place(x=500,y=150)


    tempmin=Button(window, bd=10,width=10, height = 1,text="-", font=("Helvetica", 12),command=fct_tempmin)
    tempmin.place(x=500,y=200)


    tekstvak_input_user = Entry(window, width = 10 )
    tekstvak_input_user.insert(0,19.0)
    tekstvak_input_user.place(x=350 , y=200)



    window.mainloop()`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`while True` is not needed in this program. And you have to use `.get()` to get a value inside a function. And then you should store it in a globalized variable, convert it into `int` or `float`. Then, simply use `delete(0, END)` to clear what's inside the `Entry` widget and then use `insert()` to insert the new value in the `Entry`.

Like This:

```
from tkinter import *

var = 0


def fct_temp_plus():
    global var
    var = float(tekstvak_input_user.get())
    var += 1
    tekstvak_input_user.delete(0, END)
    tekstvak_input_user.insert(0, var)


def fct_temp_min():
    global var
    var = float(tekstvak_input_user.get())
    var -= 1
    tekstvak_input_user.delete(0, END)
    tekstvak_input_user.insert(0, var)


window = Tk()
window.geometry("800x400")  # not *
window.title("TEST")

label = Label(window, text="Temp?")
label.place(x=350, y=175)


temp_plus = Button(window, bd=10, width=10, height=1, text="+", command=fct_temp_plus, font=("Helvetica", 12))
temp_plus.place(x=500, y=150)


temp_min = Button(window, bd=10, width=10, height=1, text="-", font=("Helvetica", 12), command=fct_temp_min)
temp_min.place(x=500, y=200)

tekstvak_input_user = Entry(window, width=10)
tekstvak_input_user.insert(0, 19.0)
tekstvak_input_user.place(x=350, y=200)

window.mainloop()
```

**Note:** You should always `import tkinter as tk`.

Like This:

```
import tkinter as tk

var = 0


def fct_temp_plus():
    global var
    var = float(tekstvak_input_user.get())
    var += 1
    tekstvak_input_user.delete(0, tk.END)
    tekstvak_input_user.insert(0, var)


def fct_temp_min():
    global var
    var = float(tekstvak_input_user.get())
    var -= 1
    tekstvak_input_user.delete(0, tk.END)
    tekstvak_input_user.insert(0, var)


window = tk.Tk()
window.geometry("800x400")
window.title("TEST")

label = tk.Label(window, text="Temp?")
label.place(x=350, y=175)

temp_plus = tk.Button(window, bd=10, width=10, height=1, text="+", command=fct_temp_plus, font=("Helvetica", 12))
temp_plus.place(x=500, y=150)

temp_min = tk.Button(window, bd=10, width=10, height=1, text="-", font=("Helvetica", 12), command=fct_temp_min)
temp_min.place(x=500, y=200)

tekstvak_input_user = tk.Entry(window, width=10)
tekstvak_input_user.insert(0, 19.0)
tekstvak_input_user.place(x=350, y=200)

window.mainloop()
```