# Tkinter gui field not updating when user is pressing a button

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I have made a simple gui in which I want an arbitrary number, starting at 1000, to either increase or decrease based on whether a user presses a left or right button, i.e. when a user presses the left button the given value will decrease, and when they press the right button it will increase.

Ideally I wold have had a scale or fine tune option on there as well but i was stumped at the first hurdle.

Code so far:

```
import tkinter

window = tkinter.Tk()
window.title("  Movey  ")


tkinter.Label(window, text="Current value").grid(row=0)


current_value_window = tkinter.Entry(window)

current_value_window.grid(row=0, column=1)

val_start = 1000

current_value_window.insert(0, val_start)


def lefty():
    print(val_start)
    val_start -= 10
    return val_start

def righty():
    pass

def accepty():
    pass


left_button = tkinter.Button(window, text = "Move Left", command = lefty, fg = "blue")
left_button.grid(row = 4, column = 0)

right_button = tkinter.Button(window, text = "Mover Right", command = righty, fg = "red")
right_button.grid(row = 4, column = 1)

accept_button = tkinter.Button(window, text = "OK", command = accepty, fg = "green")
accept_button.grid(row = 4, column = 2)


window.mainloop()
```

Comment: ReadTheFineTutorial: [scopes-and-namespaces](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#scopes-and-namespaces-example)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python update user input with tkinter button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59740851/python-update-user-input-with-tkinter-button)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not access or update a module-level variable inside a function. So you have to globalize it inside the function before accessing it. And you don't need to `return` the updated value just use `delete` to clear what's inside the `Entry` widget and then use `insert` to put the updated value inside the `Entry` widget.

Like this:

```
import tkinter as tk

window = tk.Tk()
window.title("  Movey  ")

tk.Label(window, text="Current value").grid(row=0)

current_value_window = tk.Entry(window)
current_value_window.grid(row=0, column=1)

val_start = 1000

current_value_window.insert(0, val_start)


def lefty():
    global val_start
    val_start -= 10
    current_value_window.delete(0, tk.END)
    current_value_window.insert(0, val_start)
    print(val_start)


def righty():
    global val_start
    val_start += 10
    current_value_window.delete(0, tk.END)
    current_value_window.insert(0, val_start)
    print(val_start)


def accepty():
    pass


left_button = tk.Button(window, text="Move Left", command=lefty, fg="blue")
left_button.grid(row=4, column=0)

right_button = tk.Button(window, text="Mover Right", command=righty, fg="red")
right_button.grid(row=4, column=1)

accept_button = tk.Button(window, text="OK", command=accepty, fg="green")
accept_button.grid(row=4, column=2)

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you Daniyal, I went through a video tutorial and came up with some thing very similar to this but did not use the current_value_window.delete etc, I didn't know you could do that, much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

What exactly is your problem? What are you looking for? Right now you only described what you try to do, but not where your actual problem is.

Some First Hints. Instead of an `Entry` try using a `Label` to display the number, otherwise, the user can just type the number in...and then the buttons wouldn't really make any sense...

Next thing I'm wondering about is your placement in the rows. In case you are trying to leave space in between the labels and the Buttons, just placing one in `row=0` and the other in `row=4` will not help, rows 1-3 have 0ptx height. You can give them some height without content with

```
    window.grid_rowconfigure("row_number",minsize="size_in_ptx")
```

Then these Rows will have a minimal height, without anything inside, so you can use them for spacing.
At last, when You try to update the Value of your `Entry` or `label` or whatever you use to display the number, it is not enough to change the value of the variable `val_start`. Look into the config method from Tkinter: [Config Description](https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-widget-configuration.htm) 
You need to reassign the value to the `Label` or `Entry`

Comment: Now I'm interested. Why am I getting a downvote? Where is the problem?

Comment: hi sxeros, I have no idea why you had a down vote, I've upvoted it anyway. As it turns out I cannot use tkinter with the .Net API I am working with at work so have to learn C# now and do the gui in that and link it to the python files I have written.

Comment: @sxeros I think that the problem is described in the title of the question "How to update a GUI field in response to the user pressing a button", which means that the problem is with updating the value inside the `Entry`. And I think that perhaps the reason for you getting a downvote is that your answer was more like a suggestion as it doesn't solve the issue. So you should have posted it as a comment, not as an answer. That's just what I think.

Comment: @Daniyal Ahmad Yea You are right, I asked for more specification because I thought that he may be just has a small problem or leaking some understandings, and is not waiting for a finished result like you gave him. But sadly I'm not allowed to write comments on others posts, bcs of me not having 50 reputation points...so I have to do it that way, I don't really understand why someone would limit users to only give comments after some reputation when that really is an important function

Comment: @sxeros I think you should stay more careful because every time you lose reputation you get far from freedom. I have managed out of that phase quite hardly. My suggestion to you is that only try to answer those questions which you think you can answer in your first attempt. And as you cannot comment on questions you should just skip those. It will take you long to find such questions but this way you will be on a safe side.

Comment: @sxeros I also suggest you to edit the answers or questions which have some grammar issues or if you think that you can clarify something in any answer or question. It will also help you gain reputation.